# Split a string with number, percentage and text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I split this string

*42% recycled nylon 41% nylon 17% elastane*

into

*42% 

recycled nylon 

41% 

nylon 

17% 

elastane*

(with regex?) ?

I have already tried and used .split(/\s(?=\d)/) but this turns the string into this :

*42% recycled nylon 

41% nylon  

17% elastane*

Thank you

Comment: Does `s.split(/\s*(\d+%)\s*/).filter(Boolean);` do what you want? Or are there other rules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're already using positive-lookahead; you can combine with positive-lookbehind:

```
(?<=\%)\s|\s(?=\d)
```

```js
var s = "42% recycled nylon 41% nylon 17% elastane";
console.log(s.split(/(?<=\%)\s|\s(?=\d)/g))
```

For a break down, see this in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MCPPI9/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:
`/(\d+%)/g`
However, that results in the output array having one or more empty strings. We can get rid of those using a neat trick with `.filter(Boolean)`. You can google the explanation of what exactly it does.

But there's a second problem. The white spaces around the strings are not removed by the regex, so you should map the array and use `.trim()` on the elements. So, your final script should be something like this:

```js
const string = "42% recycled nylon 41% nylon 17% elastane";
const regex = /(\d+%)/g;
const filtered = string.split(regex).filter(Boolean).map(i => i.trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than splitting you could match the regular expression

```
\d+%|[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*
```

with the following flags set: `i` (case indifference) and `g` ("global", meaning do not return after the first match).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QriF60/1)

The regular expression reads, "Match one or more (`+`) digits (`\d`) or (`|`) match one or more letters (`[a-z]+`) followed by one or more letters preceded by a space (`(?: [a-z]+)`), zero or more (`*`) times. `(?:...)` denotes a non-capture group.

Answer (score 0):

Since normal text and numbers with percentage are always separated with space, we can simply split the string by space and, with a combination of `.map()` and `.filter()` glue neighbors that are not numbers with percentages:

```js
let regex = /^[1-9]\d*?(.\d*)%$/g;
let arr = "42.3% recycled nylon 41% nylon 17% elastane".split(" ");
arr = arr.map(
    (item, index) => {
        if (item.match(regex)) {
            return item;
        } else {
            if ((index > 0) && (!arr[index - 1].match(regex))) {
                return "";
            } else {
                for (let subsequent = index + 1; (subsequent < arr.length) && (!arr[subsequent].match(regex)); subsequent++) {
                    if (!arr[subsequent].match(regex)) item += ` ${arr[subsequent]}`;
                }
                return item;
            }
        }
    }
).filter(item => item.length);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capture group to keep the part that is being split on, and match the optional surrounding whitespace chars.

```
\s*\b(\d+%)\s*
```

- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(\d+%)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits and `%`
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qBIirN/1).

Then remove the empty entries from the resulting array.

Or either match the start of the string or 1+ whitespace chars and either the end of the string or trailing whitespace chars if there should be nothing before or after

```
(?:^|\s+)(\d+%)(?:\s+|$)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tmkSEu/1).

```js
const regex = /\s*\b(\d+%)\s*/;
const s = `42% recycled nylon 41% nylon 17% elastane`;

console.log(s.split(regex).filter(Boolean));
```

Splitting on whitespace chars where there are either 1+ digits and % either to the left or to the right with leading or trailing whitespace boundaries:

```
 (?<=(?<!\S)\d+%)\s+|\s+(?=\d+%(?!\S))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ePg9nm/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<=(?<!\S)\d+%)\s+|\s+(?=\d+%(?!\S))/;
const s = `42% recycled nylon 41% nylon 17% elastane`;

console.log(s.split(regex));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative that assumes no digits outside of the percentages:

```js
const s = "42% recycled nylon 41% nylon 17% elastane";
const result = s.match(/[a-z ]+|[\d%]+/ig).map(e => e.trim());
console.log(result);
```

And without (much) regex, but assuming one space between each word:

```js
const s = "42% recycled nylon 41% nylon 17% elastane";
const parts = s.split(/\s+/);
const result = [];

parts.forEach((e, i) => {
  if (
    i === 0 ||
    /\d+%/.test(result.at(-1)) ||
    /\d+%/.test(e)
  ) {
    result.push(e);
  }
  else {
    result[result.length-1] += " " + e;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```